# ORA-04091 Mutating Table error during AFTER INSERT Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have the following AFTER INSERT trigger on a table called DM_USER_ROLE

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "DM_USER_ROLE_T1" 
AFTER
insert on "DM_USER_ROLE"
for each row
DECLARE 
  v_cert_enrolment_id number;
  v_user_role_id number;
begin

v_cert_enrolment_id := "DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMEN_SEQ".nextval;
v_user_role_id := :new.USER_ROLE_ID;

/*
  When a user is assigned a role, we create an enrolment record
  in DM Certification record linked to this user/role combination.
  We also insert into the DM_COURSE_ENROLMENT table the courses
  associated with the certfication
*/

--FIRST AN ENROLMENT RECORD IS CREATED IN DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT
INSERT INTO DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT
(CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT_ID, ALLOCATED_DT, DEADLINE_DATE, STATUS, USER_ROLE_ID)
VALUES
(
  v_cert_enrolment_id,
  trunc(sysdate), 
  trunc(sysdate) + 60,
  'Enrolled',
  v_user_role_id
  );

  --COURSES LINKED TO THE CERTIFICATION ARE INSERTED INTO DM_COURSE_ENROLMENT
INSERT INTO DM_COURSE_ENROLMENT
  (
    CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT_ID,
    COURSE_ID,
    ALLOCATED_DT,
    DEADLINE_DT,
    STATUS
    )
SELECT v_cert_enrolment_id,
       COURSE.COURSE_ID,
       trunc(sysdate),
       trunc(sysdate) + 60,
       'Enrolled'
FROM DM_CERTIFICATION_COURSE COURSE
WHERE CERTIFICATION_ID = 
(
  SELECT  C.CERTIFICATION_ID FROM 
    DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT A, 
    DM_USER_ROLE B,
    DM_ROLE_CERTIFICATION C
  WHERE 
    A.USER_ROLE_ID = B.USER_ROLE_ID 
    AND 
    B.ROLE_ID = C.ROLE_ID
    AND 
    A.CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT_ID = v_cert_enrolment_id
);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQLERRM(-20299)));
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 2000));




end;
```

I need to populate 2 separate tables when an insert happens in this table, and I thought AFTER INSERT triggers avoided issues with mutating tables?

I am not sure what is causing it, perhaps the read in the second INSERT statement from DM_USER_ROLE, which is where this trigger is initiated...but I was under the impression AFTER INSERTs were safe to avoid mutations, as the update has already happened.

Error is:

> ORA-04091: table AZLEARN_BACKUP.DM_USER_ROLE is mutating,
>   trigger/function may not see it

The first insert happens, the second one does not.

This article led me to believe AFTER triggers were safe.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm

-------UPDATE---------------

I changed it to do row by row insert using two parameterised cursors and it worked...still not sure what the error was:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "DM_USER_ROLE_T1" 
AFTER
insert on "DM_USER_ROLE"
for each row
DECLARE 
  v_cert_enrolment_id number;
  v_user_role_id number;
  v_role_id number;
  v_certification_id number;

 cursor certs_for_role(p_role_id number) is
  select * from DM_ROLE_CERTIFICATION where ROLE_ID = p_role_id;

 r_certs_for_role certs_for_role%rowtype;

  cursor courses_for_certs(p_cert_id number) is
  select * from DM_CERTIFICATION_COURSE where CERTIFICATION_ID = p_cert_id;

  r_courses_for_certs courses_for_certs%rowtype;

begin


v_user_role_id := :new.USER_ROLE_ID;
v_role_id := :new.ROLE_ID;


open certs_for_role(v_role_id);
loop
  fetch certs_for_role into r_certs_for_role;  
    exit when certs_for_role%notfound;
      v_cert_enrolment_id := "DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMEN_SEQ".nextval;

      INSERT INTO DM_CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT
      (CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT_ID, ALLOCATED_DT, DEADLINE_DATE, STATUS, USER_ROLE_ID, CERTIFICATION_ID)
      VALUES
      (
        v_cert_enrolment_id,
        trunc(sysdate), 
        trunc(sysdate) + 60,
        'Enrolled',
        v_user_role_id,
        r_certs_for_role.CERTIFICATION_ID
      );

    open courses_for_certs(r_certs_for_role.CERTIFICATION_ID);
      loop
        fetch courses_for_certs into r_courses_for_certs;
        exit when courses_for_certs%notfound;
        INSERT INTO DM_COURSE_ENROLMENT
        (
          CERTIFICATION_ENROLMENT_ID,
          COURSE_ID,
          ALLOCATED_DT,
          DEADLINE_DT,
          STATUS
        )
        VALUES
        (
          v_cert_enrolment_id,
          r_courses_for_certs.COURSE_ID,
          trunc(sysdate),
          trunc(sysdate) + 60,
          'Enrolled'        
        );    
      end loop;
    close courses_for_certs;
end loop;

close certs_for_role;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQLERRM(-20299)));
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 2000));




end;
```

Comment: If you can insert one row at a time to avoid the mutation, then the apparent flaw in the business logic might be more easy to see.

Comment: Interestingly the first insert happens, the second one doesn't - I would have thought this would be treated as a transaction. How would I insert one row at a time, with a cursor?

Comment: I think, you should implement this logic in a procedure/function.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simply you cannot select from table `DM_USER_ROLE` where the ROW LEVEL trigger is based on.

In your first solution you have a

```
SELECT ...
FROM DM_USER_ROLE ...
```

This is not allowed. Your second trigger does not select table `DM_USER_ROLE` thus it is working.

The advise in linked page is correct but misleading when they state 'Use an "after" or "instead of" trigger' - It should be more precisely 'Use an "after statement" or "instead of" trigger' . Oracle provides triggers based on following actions:

- DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on a particular table or view
- DDL statements (CREATE or ALTER primarily)
- Database events, such as logon/logoff, errors, or startup/shutdown

You have a DML trigger which can have different timing points:

- Before the triggering statement executes
- After the triggering statement executes
- Before each row that the triggering statement affects
- After each row that the triggering statement affects
- Compound Trigger -> this one combines the four triggers listed above
- INSTEAD OF Trigger (only for views)

Many people miss the difference between a statement level trigger and a row level trigger.

Row Level Triggers have keyword `FOR EACH ROW` and run for each row like the keyword implies. If you skip the `FOR EACH ROW` keyword, then the trigger is executed only once for each statement, no matter how many rows are affected by your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of a mutating table error is the misuse of `triggers`. Here is a typical example:

> 1.you insert a row in table A
>
> 2.a trigger on table A (for each row) executes a query on table A, for example to compute a summary column
>
> 3.Oracle throws an ORA-04091: table A is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

This is an expected and normal behaviour, Oracle wants to protect you from yourself since Oracle guarantees:

> •(i) that each statement is atomic (i.e will either fail or succeed
>   completely)
>
> •(ii) that each statement sees a consistent view of the data

Now in your trigger, when you do the second insert, it's doing a join on the `DM_USER_ROLE` table to fetch the records and that's the reason you face

> ORA-04091: table AZLEARN_BACKUP.DM_USER_ROLE is mutating,
>   trigger/function may not see it